# Prove that graph contains a quadrangle

Tags: graph-theory

There is given a bipartite graph $G$ in which:
Vertices: $V(G) = A ∪ B$, $A ∩ B = \emptyset$, $|A|=|B|=20$,
Edges:  $E ⊆ \{\,vw : v ∈ A, w ∈ B\,\}$ and $|E|=99$. Prove that graph contains a quadrangle (a cycle of length 4)

Comment: Yeah, I tried to solve it, used handshaking lemma but it got me nowhere, it's a new type of problem for me and I still have difficulties with this

Comment: And a quadrangle is a cycle of length 4, I presume?

Comment: Exactly, I'll edit that

Comment: What's the source of this problem, please?

Comment: Possibly helpful fact: Bipartite graphs can only contain cycles of even length

Comment: [Problem 6 from the Polish Mathematical Olympiad](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/25020/polish-mathematical-olympiad-2016-17) @GerryMyerson.

Answer (score 1):

If $v\in A$ has $\rho(v)$ neighbours, it has ${\rho(v)\choose 2}=\frac12\rho^2(v)-\frac12\rho(v)$ pairs of neighbours. We know $\sum_{v\in A}\rho(v)=99$, hence
$$\sum{{\rho(v)\choose 2}} =\frac12\sum\rho^2(v)-\frac{99}2$$
and it is well-known (quick proof: If $0\le a< b-1$ then $(a+1)^2+(b-1)^2=a^2+b^2+2a-2b+2<a^2+b^2 $) that the sum of squares (for fixed sum) is minimal when the summands are as equal as possible, i.e. 
$$\sum\rho^2(v)\ge 4^2+5^2+\ldots+5^2 =491$$
and so
$$ \tag1\sum{{\rho(v)\choose 2}}\ge 196$$
As there are only ${20\choose 2}=190<196$ pairs of points in $B$ possible, at least one of these pairs must be counted repeatedly in $(1)$, thus leading to a quadrangle.